# Get Weekday from int

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum

```
public enum Weekday {
    Sunday(0), Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thursday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6);
    private int value;

    private Weekday(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }



}
```

And I can get the value from the day if I know what day I want, and I am having a brain freeze right now and am trying to do the oppostie. And cant figure it out

So I know I have number 2 and then want to return a variable of Weekday type Tuesday?

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Note that in your specific case, where the int values are 0-6, the built-ins `values()` and `ordinal()` will already do what you want, and you don't need the field.

Comment: Oh @chrylis but it doesn't hurt to have them there just as a reminder to me right?

Comment: You can if you want, it'll just make the class a lot longer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Map and then create a method like `getByCode`, where you will pass the day number as the argument and it will return you the enum. E.g.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

enum Weekday {
    Sunday(0), Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thursday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6);
      private int value;

      Weekday(int c){
         this.value =c;
      }


      static Map<Integer, Weekday> map = new HashMap<>();

      static {
         for (Weekday catalog : Weekday.values()) {
            map.put(catalog.value, catalog);
         }
      }

      public static Weekday getByCode(int code) {
         return map.get(code);
      }
   }
```

You can call the above method like `Weekday.getByCode(2)` and it will return you `Tuesday`

Comment: prefect! Thanks I just blanked real hard there :)

Comment: Workable, but if the values are definitely going to be sequential starting from zero, just use the built-ins.

Comment: @chrylis Yes but that way we are depending on ordinal and if by mistake someone declared Tuesday before Monday e.g.`Sunday(0), Tuesday(2), Monday(1), Wednesday(3), Thursday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6);` then result will be wrong

Comment: If they got that declaration wrong, they'd probably get the field wrong, too.

Comment: @chrylis Might be, but IMO it's better not to make code dependent on enum position , so that we can refactor easily and confidently .

Comment: @iqueqiorio , Glad it helps , you can always upvote and accept it as answer if it answer your question precisely :)

Answer (score 1):

`Weekday.values()` returns an array with all enum values.
Each enum value has a method `ordinal()`, which returns it's index in the enum declaration.

In **this case, where the value is equal to the index**, you can simplify your code:

```
public enum Weekday {
    Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday;
}
```

Get the value:

```
Weekday.Sunday.ordinal()
```

Get the enum value:

```
Weekday.values()[value]
```

Comment: can you explain this Weekday.Sunday.ordinal() so I can vote u up?

Comment: I recommend the JavaDocs.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal-- I wouldn't be able to explain more than them.